# How to prioritize the validation constraints

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

I have an email field that has both required attribute and type=email. It shows two error messages at a time. How to restrict to only one error message at a time. How do I set the priority between 'required' and type="email".

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Are you talking about the browser's error messages? Or, are you using some type of JS framework to perform validations?

Comment: @YosepKim: she is using parsley.js based on the tags

Answer (score 1):

By default, Parsley prioritize itself the various constraints applied to a field, and shows only the most important error message first.

Please, ensure:

- that you are using latest parsley version (2.0.0): http://parsleyjs.org/doc/download.html
- that the `priorityEnabled` option is untouched or set to `true` in your configuration: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html#section-6

Best

Comment: I am using the latest version 2.0.0. The parsley validation is not stopping at the first constraint failure. The parsley error list has more than one message at any point of time.

Comment: Please give me then a jsfiddle in order to look what is the problem. Thanks